# php array will not clear

Tags: php, html, arrays

I'm struggling with clearing out an array when "clearYes" radio button is checked upon submit. It will appear to clear but as soon as I list the contents of the array everything is there again.

Here is the code

```
<?php
session_start();

// Initialize an array for answers
if (!isset($_SESSION['songArr']))
    $_SESSION['songArr'] = array();
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>

<body>

    <form name="songform" action="" onsubmit=" return validateForm()" method="post">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <th>Song Name:</th>
                <th><input type="text" name="songName" size="20"></th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>Composer:</th>
                <th><input type="text" name="composer" size="20"></th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>Artist or Group:</th>
                <th><input type="text" name="artist" size="20"></th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <p><input name="radio1" type="radio" value="listSongs"> Show the list of songs? </p>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <p><input name="submit" type="submit" value="Submit Song" /> <input type="reset" value="Clear form" /></p>
        <p><input name="radio2" type="radio" value="clearNo" checked="checked"> Don't clear list. <input name="radio2" type="radio" value="clearYes">Clear list after submit.</p>
    </form>

</body>

<?php
if (!empty($_POST['submit'])) {
// Push the posted data into the session array
$_SESSION['songArr'][] = $_POST;
}
$listSongs= $_POST['radio1'];
// Display the data now
//if clearYes is selected
if ($listSongs == "listSongs") {
foreach($_SESSION['songArr'] as $array) {
    echo "<strong>Song name</strong>: {$array['songName']}<br>";
    echo "<strong>Composer</strong>: {$array['composer']}<br>";
    echo "<strong>Artists</strong>: {$array['artist']}<br><br>";
}
}
//if clearYes is selected
$resetArr= $_POST['radio1'];
if ($resetArr == "clearYes") {
unset($array);
$array = array();
session_start();
session_unset();
session_destroy();
session_write_close();
setcookie(session_name(),'',0,'/');
session_regenerate_id(true);
}
?>

</html>
```

Comment: Try `unset($_SESSION['songArr']);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to unset the source array :

Replace :

```
 unset($array);
```

With :

```
 unset($_SESSION['songArr']);
```

Hope it helps.